# Regex for javascript to count words (excluding numbers)

Tags: regex

I have this function

```
String.prototype.countWords = function(){
    return this.split(/\s+\b/).length;
}
```

which counts words in textarea, but it also counts numbers inserted, I was wondering how to count words but not numbers, so ignoring the numbers,

Comment: can you provide an input sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex might help you out:

```
String.prototype.countWords = function(){
    return this.split(/\s+[^0-9]/).length;
}
```

The `^` negates the characters in the brackets, so all characters are allowed to follow the whitespaces except any numbers.

By the way: here is a good place to test your regex: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your regex counts the number of spaces.. Use the following for words (without numbers):

```
/[a-zA-Z]+/
```

For splitting use the following:

```
this.split(/[\s\D]+/).length
```

Comment: thank you but it count numebrs as well, and I don't want to include numbers in the count. Is there a way to ignore them?

Comment: @Useer         use `[^0-9]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`. It shouldn't make any difference tbh.